# Which asymmetric cipher provides the highest performance?

Tags: pki

To get the highest performance, which asymmetric cipher provides the fastest encryption/decryption? ECC or DH? What key size is recommended today?

Comment: This can change drastically based on hardware support and the particular implementation you choose. When in doubt, benchmark.

Comment: @Stephen Touset cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html seems RSA is fastest ?! ECC 13.20  RSA 1.46

Comment: @rsa RSA is fast for *encryption* but really slow for *decryption*. You're comparing different security levels and you're not looking at a good ECC implementation.

Comment: Are you talking about *bulk* encryption/decryption of large amounts of data? Or are you talking about large *numbers) of encryption/decryption operations of small amounts of data? (If the former, I think you don't understand how asymmetric ciphers are used.)

Comment: @rsa When in doubt, benchmark *on your own hardware with the implementations you have available*. If performance is important, nobody can answer this question except for you.

Comment: @David Schwartz i talking about large *numbers) of encryption/decryption operations of small amounts of data!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer a ~128 bit security level. With ECC this means a curve with ~256 bits, with DH or RSA this corresponds to around 3000 bits. If you can accept a lower security level, the advantage of ECC over DH/RSA gets smaller.

My favourite is Curve25519, which has easily available [high performance](http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-dh.html) implementations. An alternative is P256 which is a NIST standard, but a bit slower. There are also some other curves/implementations which are faster than Curve25519, but those seem more academic.